# WPF Listbox Selected Item Style (Highlighting is Overriding Data-Triggered Style)

Tags: wpf, user-controls, listbox, wpf-controls

I am an Access developer moving into .Net and I have a WPF project.  Since I am used to subforms in Access, I created user controls to act this way (may be an issue itself, but not something I am addressing at the moment).

This particular user control (subform) has several listboxes that are bound to objects in the code behind (VB -- I am not getting into that debate either; I am familiar with VBA).  These listboxes are bound to a boolean value called "IsAssigned".  I created a style to change the items in these listboxes to Greenish or Reddish depending upon that value.  This is working.

I then wanted to change the value to override the window's Highlight behavior and learned about the SystemColors.HighlightColor and ControlBrushKey.  The problem is that I want the HighlightColor and ControlBrushKey colors to be dependent upon the "IsAssigned" value.  I apparently can't nest triggers unless I am missing someting.  In the following code I have the highlight values set to Green just for an illustration of where I am in my understanding of this.

So what I want is that when an item is selected, the text is bolded, with a black border, and maintains a solid color of green or red depending on the "IsAssigned" value.  When that same item is the highlighted item, I would really like the forecolor to be white and maybe have a thicker border.

Be gentle -- I am a noob in more ways than one.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ColorTrueAndFalse">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" Color="Green" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAssigned}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="LawnGreen" Offset="2" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAssigned}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="LightCoral" Offset="0.5" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Coral" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="2" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the `ListBoxItem` is different from the one of the `ListBox` itself.
When using `{Binding IsAssigned}` inside the `ListBoxItem`'s style, you're not using the same `DataContext` as the `ListBox` and therefor you can't find the property.

This can easily fixed by using **Relative Binding** - for example:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.IsAssigned}" Value="true">
```

This tries to bind to the ListBoxItems' parent. It goes up the Visual Tree until it finds the ListBox and tries to use the former's `DataContext` property to find the IsAssigned.

So a complete solution will look something like this:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    </Trigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.IsAssigned}" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Background">
          ....
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
```

**Update** - For highlighting:

First notice the name of the Highlight brush is `HighlightBrushKey` not as you wrote:

```
<Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
```

Second - Instead of the `Trigger` you used, use this `DataTrigger` to change the selected item's properties:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  This solution does not handle the problem though.  Bear with me:  The style on the listboxitems are working fine in terms of the datacontext. It shows the green brush when IsAssigned = true and red when false.  The problem is the highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Well after a lot of pulling out what little hair I have left, and some pointers in the right direction from Blachshma, I came up with a solution.  It is mainly based off of the markup [found here](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/06/28/background-color-for-wpf-listbox-selected-item.aspx).

The HighlightBrushKey and  ControlBrushKey were giving me grief -- I could not get them to recognize the underlying color already set by a data trigger.  I could set it to a static color, but nothing dynamic.  Perhaps with more time invested this would have worked.  Instead, I used the border to set the color in the data trigger and changed the font and opacity of any selected items.  The border color still remained the same, even after selecting an item in one listbox and moving away to select another item in another listbox, which is exactly what I wanted.

**Here is my XAML (with certain details left out for the sake of brevity):**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="BorderTrueAndFalse">
        <Style.Resources>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TrueBrush" EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                ...
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="FalseBrush" EndPoint="0,0.5" StartPoint="1,0.5">
                ...
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border  Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAssigned}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TrueBrush}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAssigned}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FalseBrush}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".8"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Of course, I believe that I am ony 80% sure of what is going on here, but the process has given me a deeper understanding of binding, triggers, styles, templates, and why Access stuff is developed so much faster!  Maybe someday I will set the text to spin, flash, and get up to do a little jig, but for now I am a happy camper.